# How to get scrapy results orderly?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Help me with scrapy. My code resulting output however it doesn't print the corrected way.

I also tried with inside another for loop but that will not give correct result, Anyway if you found something missing in there.. please tel me

Code:

```
import scrapy

class YelpScrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yelp'
    start_urls = ["http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Pet+Grooming+Services&find_loc=Starnberg%2C+Bayern",]

    def print_link(self, link):
        return link

    def parse(self, response):
        website = scrapy.Selector(response)
        items = []

        for obj in website.xpath("//div[@class='main-attributes']"):
            item = YelpItem()

            # Getting name
            item['name'] = obj.xpath("//div[@class='media-story']//h3//a/text()").extract()

            # Getting addresss
            item['address'] = obj.xpath("//div[@class='secondary-attributes']//address").extract()

            items.append(item)

        return items
```

The resulting output comes like:

```
 'name': [u'Tierschutzverein Starnberg u. Umgebung',
              u'M\xfcmmelpension',
              u'Hundesportverein Starnberg e. V.',
              u'Bellness Hundesalon',
              u'California Dog Spa',
              u'Gassi Germering',
              u'Hundesalon Tanaka Beauty & Spa',
              u'Hundesalon Popp',
              u'Neuhauser Hundeladen',
              u'TheraFelis Katja R\xfcssel'],

{'address': [u'<address>\n            Franziskusweg 34<br>82319 Starnberg<br>Germany\n        </address>',
                 u'<address>\n            St.-Michael-Str. 19<br>82319 Starnberg<br>Germany\n        </address>',
                 u'<address>\n            J\xe4gersbrunner Str. 1<br>82319 Starnberg<br>Germany\n        </address>',
                 u'<address>\n            Baierbrunner Str. 1<br>81379 Munich<br>Germany\n        </address>',
                 u'<address>\n            Geigenbergerstr. 51<br>81477 Solln<br>Germany\n        </address>',
                 u'<address>\n            Donnersbergerstr. 30<br>80634 Munich<br>Germany\n        </address>',
                 u'<address>\n            Els\xe4sser Stra\xdfe 24<br>81667 Munich<br>Germany\n        </address>',
                 u'<address>\n            Schluderstr. 40<br>80634 Munich<br>Germany\n        </address>',
                 u'<address>\n            Fliederstr.  23<br>82131 Gauting<br>Germany\n        </address>'],
```

Why it's not coming in the order like `{{name, address}{name, address}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your locators match multiple elements and are not context-specific (should start with a dot), fix it:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for obj in response.css("ul.search-results li"):
        item = YelpItem()

        item['name'] = obj.xpath(".//div[@class='media-story']//h3//a/text()").extract()[0]
        item['address'] = ''.join(obj.xpath(".//div[@class='secondary-attributes']//address/text()").extract()).strip()

        yield item
```

Comment: Thank you.. your logic is correct and it resulting the correct way but I'm getting the repeated result.. can you correct it ?